# C# server and client communication - send/receive data

Tags: c#, send

I need to help, I want to make server and client, who will communicate together.(send/receive data)

Example: client sends username and password to server when I login and server checks it and sends (correct or not correct) to client.

Server and client can send and receive data, and more data together (for example: username, password ... in one communication)

I need from you the best example of communicating with the client, server, currently I have this script by youtube: [enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=INrcHZBhB20&list=PLLITw-6k1t1Zo7kxm4GAGOkeFJqW-7QPt)

There is send / receive method from youtube:

```
public class PacketWriter : BinaryWriter
{
    // This will hold our packet bytes.
    private MemoryStream _ms;

    // We will use this to serialize (Not in this tutorial)
    private BinaryFormatter _bf;

    public PacketWriter() : base()
    {
        // Initialize our variables
        _ms = new MemoryStream();
        _bf = new BinaryFormatter();

        // Set the stream of the underlying BinaryWriter to our memory stream.
        OutStream = _ms;
    }

    public void Write(Image image)
    {
        var ms = new MemoryStream(); //Create a memory stream to store our image bytes.

        image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png); //Save the image to the stream.

        ms.Close(); //Close the stream.

        byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray(); //Grab the bytes from the stream.

        //Write the image bytes to our memory stream
        //Length then bytes
        Write(imageBytes.Length);
        Write(imageBytes);
    }

    public void WriteT(object obj)
    {
        //We use the BinaryFormatter to serialize our object to the stream.
        _bf.Serialize(_ms, obj);
    }

    public byte[] GetBytes()
    {
        Close(); //Close the Stream. We no longer have need for it.

        byte[] data = _ms.ToArray(); //Grab the bytes and return.

        return data;
    }
}

public class PacketReader : BinaryReader
{
    // This will be used for deserializing
    private BinaryFormatter _bf;

    public PacketReader(byte[] data) : base(new MemoryStream(data))
    {
        _bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    }

    public Image ReadImage()
    {
        //Read the length first as we wrote it.
        int len = ReadInt32();
        //Read the bytes
        byte[] bytes = ReadBytes(len);

        Image img; //This will hold the image.

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            img = Image.FromStream(ms); //Get the image from the stream of the bytes.
        }

        return img; //Return the image.
    }

    public T ReadObject<T>()
    {
        //Use the BinaryFormatter to deserialize the object and return it casted as T
        /* MSDN Generics
         * http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx
         */
        return (T)_bf.Deserialize(BaseStream);
    }
}
```

I don't know if it is better method, I don't have experience with it, so I want to ask someone more experienced.

Is good method make images from data and send?

Thank you for any advice, I will be grateful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [this CodeProject example](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1415/Introduction-to-TCP-client-server-in-C), it seems to be what you're looking for. You'll need two separate applications, one for your server and the other for your client.

**Server:** Essentially all you need to do here is open up a TcpListener and receive the bytes from it. From the CodeProject article:

```
    using System;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Sockets;

    public class serv {
        public static void Main() {
        try {
            IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse("172.21.5.99");
             // use local m/c IP address, and 
             // use the same in the client

    /* Initializes the Listener */
            TcpListener myList=new TcpListener(ipAd,8001);

    /* Start Listening at the specified port */        
            myList.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("The server is running at port 8001...");    
            Console.WriteLine("The local End point is  :" + 
                              myList.LocalEndpoint );
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection.....");

            Socket s = myList.AcceptSocket();
            Console.WriteLine("Connection accepted from " + s.RemoteEndPoint);

            byte[] b=new byte[100];
            int k=s.Receive(b);
            Console.WriteLine("Recieved...");
            for (int i=0;i<k;i++)
                Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(b[i]));

            ASCIIEncoding asen=new ASCIIEncoding();
            s.Send(asen.GetBytes("The string was recieved by the server."));
            Console.WriteLine("\nSent Acknowledgement");
            s.Close();
            myList.Stop();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine("Error..... " + e.StackTrace);
        }    
    }        
}
```

**Client:** The client is pretty similar, except instead of using a TcpListener, you'd use a TcpClient. Again from CodeProject:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;


public class clnt {

    public static void Main() {

        try {
            TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting.....");

            tcpclnt.Connect("172.21.5.99",8001);
            // use the ipaddress as in the server program

            Console.WriteLine("Connected");
            Console.Write("Enter the string to be transmitted : ");

            String str=Console.ReadLine();
            Stream stm = tcpclnt.GetStream();

            ASCIIEncoding asen= new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] ba=asen.GetBytes(str);
            Console.WriteLine("Transmitting.....");

            stm.Write(ba,0,ba.Length);

            byte[] bb=new byte[100];
            int k=stm.Read(bb,0,100);

            for (int i=0;i<k;i++)
                Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(bb[i]));

            tcpclnt.Close();
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine("Error..... " + e.StackTrace);
        }
    }
}
```

This is a very basic example of how you can do some simple networking tasks in .Net; if you're planning on creating web-based applications I'd recommend you use WCF/Asp.Net.

Comment: At the time it seemed like he wanted to use a .Net ecosystem. Even in 18 months times have changed, web development is a highly explosive and constantly evolving landscape. Using WCF is not a popular choice for most new projects nowadays, even in a Microsoft sandbox.